# Add to current selection where a field has the same attribute

Tags: arcgis-pro, select

I have a selection set on a feature class. I'd like to add to that selection set where the additional rows I'm selecting have an attribute that is the same as an attribute for already selected rows.

Example: Rows 1, 2, 3, 4 have attribute 'Letter': "A", "B", "B", "C" respectively, and row 3 is already selected. Row 2 has the same attribute, so it should be added to the selection set.

Answer (score 1):

you can summarise your selected records depending on the field you wish to select further records from (letter in this case). A new table will be created that only contains sum of entries (rows) with the required letter field. Now you can relate this table from join & relates option with your feature layer. Relate will be based on the letter field. Now both tables are related. Whatever you select in relate table will automatically select features from your layer by clicking related table.[image]